# How to fix the execution expired in Selenium Webdriver in Ruby with rpsec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

I'm trying to run a test that answers form done in angularjs. 
When I run the test, after a while I keep getting this error as below. I have tried to catch the exception with StandardError but I would like to find out fix for this issue.

- ***Ruby:*** ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32].
- ***Selenium:*** SeleniumServerStandalone-2.47.1.jar and SeleniumServerStandalone-3.4.0.jar.

(I have tried both the Selenium Server to see if the latest one would fix it with no luck).

```
Failure/Error: base_question.complete
         Timeout::Error:
           execution expired
         # ./lib/api/page_model.rb:175:in 'sleep'
         # ./lib/api/page_model.rb:175:in 'block in until'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in 'block in timeout'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in 'block in catch'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in 'catch'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in 'catch'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:106:in 'timeout'
         # ./lib/api/page_model.rb:170:in 'until'
         # ./lib/api/ais_page_model.rb:951:in 'answer'
         # ./lib/api/ais_page_model.rb:812:in 'complete'
         # ./lib/api/ais_page_model.rb:676:in 'complete'
         # ./spec/core/ui/multithread/answers.rb:178:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./lib/patches/rspec.rb:24:in 'instance_eval'
         # ./lib/patches/rspec.rb:24:in 'block in run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:253:in 'with_around_each_hooks'
         # ./lib/patches/rspec.rb:21:in 'run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:378:in 'block in run_examples'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:374:in 'map'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:374:in 'run_examples'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:360:in 'run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in 'block (2 levels) in run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in 'map'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in 'block in run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in 'report'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in 'run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in 'run'
         # C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in 'block in autorun'
```

Code at line 175

```
def until
  raise NestedWaitCallError if Kernel.caller.any? { |caller| caller.include?(__method__.to_s) }
  raise "no block given" unless block_given?
  Timeout::timeout(self) do
    delay = 0.1
    begin
     until yield
       sleep delay
       delay *= 2
     end
     rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError, Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
     sleep delay
     delay *= 2
     retry
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the code which is causing this error? It looks like it will be around line 175 of ./lib/api/page_model.rb

Comment: Please see updated code above.